# Logging module in Python printing same error multiple times and sending mail multiple times

Tags: python, logging, smtp

I am trying to send an error message in a mail. Below is my code, which is sending same error mail 3-4 times and also writing to a log file multiple times. How to fix this? In below code I removed first character from url to create error.

```
def get_logger(    
        LOG_FORMAT     = '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        LOG_NAME       = '',
        LOG_FILE_INFO  = 'file.log',
        LOG_FILE_ERROR = 'file.err'):

    log           = logging.getLogger(LOG_NAME)
    if not len(log.handlers):
        log_formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMAT)

        file_handler_error = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE_ERROR, mode='w')
        file_handler_error.setFormatter(log_formatter)
        file_handler_error.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        log.addHandler(file_handler_error)
        log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        #email sending
        smtp_handler = logging.SMTPHandler(mailhost=("smtp.gmail.com", 25),
                                                fromaddr="abcd@gmail.com", 
                                                toaddrs="xyz@gmail.com",
                                                subject=u"Job App error!",
                                                credentials=('abcd@gmail.com', 'xxxxx'),
                                                secure=())

        log.addHandler(smtp_handler)

    return log

def main():

try:
        url = 'ttp://www.google.com'
        response = requests.get(url)

except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e.message)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = get_logger()
    main()
```

Comment: We cannot reproduce anything with this example, can you confirm that your code does not throw multiple errors ? Maybe you can add some of the related variables to the log message to check that

Comment: @PRMoureu added small piece of code in try block to get some error. can you please check it

Comment: so this code is generating an error multiples times ?